# Spring WS force SOAP endpoint operation name

Tags: java, spring, soap

I am implementing a SOAP WS with spring, I have my XSDs, then I add my endpoints with annotations such as:

```
@Endpoint
public class StuffRequestEndpoint {

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = "urn:mycomp-com/xyz/ws/msg", localPart = "StuffRequest")
    public
    @ResponsePayload
    StuffResponse requestStuff(@RequestPayload StuffRequest request) {
```

The problem I have is that the produced WSDL has a funny operation name:

```
    <wsdl:operation name="Stuff">
        <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
        <wsdl:input name="StuffRequest">
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="StuffResponse">
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
```

How could I override the produced operation name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well I see this is pretty old and I too do not have a direct answer, what I did was basically renaming the object to what I want the action be named like.

Since Spring-WS looks at the xsd and if it sees name with Request/Response suffix it creates an action with such name, e.g. object `GetListOfCitiesRequest` would be `GetListOfCities` action. In your case that could be something like this in XSD

`<xs:element name="GetListOfCitiesRequest">`

which would then appear like this wsdl generated by spring-ws

```
<wsdl:operation name="GetListOfCities">
    <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
    <wsdl:input name="GetListOfCitiesRequest">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:input>
</wsdl:operation>
```